# Vendor Credit Complete SOAP API Call

Tags: netsuite

I want to apply vendor Credit to an existing vendor bill via SOAP API....

can someone please share a working Vendor Credit Soap API call with vendor bill link included in it.

Thanks

I tried couple of samples and none of them seem to be working....Can someone please provide a complete working Vendor Credit SOAP API call with Vendorbill link included in it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Also worth taking the [tour]. This is off-topic as written: there's no programming question; just a high-level set of requirements, followed by a request for the Community to create/provide a sample for you.